# how to use sum() in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have a table `total_count`

```
id  studid  month   year     acls_id   total_p total_a 

1   30       08     2015        12        5      2      
2   35       08     2015        12        5      2      
3   52       08     2015        12        5      2      
4   53       08     2015        12        5      2  
5   54       08     2015        12        5      2  
6   55       08     2015        12        5      2  
7   30       09     2015        12        3      0  
8   35       09     2015        12        3      0  
9   52       09     2015        12        2      1  
10  53       09     2015        12        3      0  
11  54       09     2015        12        3      0  
12  55       09     2015        12        3      0
```

I want to calculate for each student `total_p` and `total_a`.

eg: `studid = 30`, `total_p = 5`  and `total_a = 2`.

So I'd like to get the total of each month for each `studid` and a sum of  `total_p` and `total_a` for the total months.

My controller code is

```
$total_counts = DB::table('total_count')
                       ->whereBetween('smonth',08, 09))
                       ->whereBetween('syear', 2015, 2015))   
                       ->sum('total_p);
                       ->sum('total_a);
```

view blade.php

```
{{$total_counts->total_p}}
{{$total_counts->total_a}}
```

but it doesn't work..

How to use `sum()` in query builder format?

I would like an output like:

```
  studid     total_p   total_a

    30          8         2

    35          8         2

    52          7         3

    53          8         2

    54          8         2

    55          8         2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eloquent's aggregate function **sum()** returns a single scalar for all rows matching criterai. If you want to get a list of rows, you'll need to build a query that groups students by their ID and calculate the sums for each of them.

This query should do the trick:

```
$total_counts = DB::table('total_count')
  ->whereBetween('smonth',08, 09))
  ->whereBetween('syear', 2015, 2015))
  ->groupBy('studid')
  ->get(['studid', DB::raw('SUM(total_a) AS sum_a'), DB::raw('SUM(total_p) AS sum_p')]);
```

Each row in **$total_counts** will contain 3 values: **studid**, **sum_a** and **sum_p**.

Comment: Eg:studid 30 total_p = 5 and total_a= 2 ,so iam edit my attendance present become absent .

so want decrement total_p by 1 and increment total_a by 1.

Comment: Iam using this code DB::table($wys_total_attend_table)->whereIn('studid',[$student->id])
                          ->where('smonth',$date_exploded[1])
                          ->where('syear',$date_exploded[2])
                          ->where('stotal_a','!=',0)
                   ->increment('stotal_a', 1,['studid' => $student->id])
                 ->decrement('stotal_p', 1,['studid' => $student->id]);.but not work properly...

Comment: I'm just checking your other question as we speak